# if i want to blur an image using a 45 motion blur involving the 11 pixels to the lower-left of a given pixel?

Tags: image, image-processing

My guess is that the matrix will be

http://tinypic.com/r/14y8fmg/5

so i will begin with the given pixel as the top right end of the matrix , but my question is the given matrix is 12 by 12 matrix , should all the filter matrices be odd by odd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason to make a filter odd is to have a well defined center. Since you are filtering using the corner of the filter as your anchor it doesn't matter.